# I made a PDF generator using FPDF and PHP, but it only works after a refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, fpdf

My PDF only displays after I refresh the page, otherwise it turns into weird symbols. When it does display, its fullscreen (header disappears) and when I press go back, the URL changes, but the page still displays the DPF, and when I refresh, this fixes itself again.

Im also using JQuery Mobile, maybe this has something to do with it.

Here is some code:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hondensectie</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/themerollertest.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
```

This is the head ^^

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="header" style="overflow:hidden;" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>PDF Maker</h1>
    <a href="stafindex.php" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-back ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-icon-notext">Back</a>
    <a href="stafindex.php" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left ui-btn-icon-notext">Home</a>

</div>
<div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
<div data-role="collapsible" data-content-theme="a">      
<h4>Gebruikers</h4>
<p>              
    <section id="hondppp" data-ajax='false'>
    <?php
        ob_start();
        //call the FPDF library
        require('fpdfmap/fpdf.php');

        //A4 width : 219mm
        //default margin : 10mm each side
        //writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm

        //create pdf object
        $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
        //add new page
        $pdf->AddPage();
        $pdf->Output();
        ob_end_flush();
    ?>   
    </section>
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before you call the output function use the `ob_end_clean` function to remove and discard any other output that may have already been sent to the browser.

```
$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();
ob_end_clean();  // clear out anything that may have already been output
$pdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to display a PDF file, the server has to return a response that contains `Content-Type: application/pdf` header in it. As far as I know, `FPDF` sets this header when `Output` function is called. However, no headers can be set after the response is sent, and this usually happens with the first line of HTML being displayed with your PHP script. Actually I'm surprised that you can ever see the PDF, and that you don't get the infamous "headers already sent" error (although that one probably shows somewhere in the logs, if you know where to look).

The point is, don't write any HTML before or after the PDF content. Your entire PHP script should just contain these lines:

```
    //call the FPDF library
    require('fpdfmap/fpdf.php');

    //A4 width : 219mm
    //default margin : 10mm each side
    //writable horizontal : 219-(10*2)=189mm

    //create pdf object
    $pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
    //add new page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Output();
```